# Python Password Checker Program - Comparison with .pop() value not working

Tags: python, list

I have started to create a password checker program for part of my assignment. It takes an initial input from the user, stores it in an external file, then takes another input and checks if both inputs match. If they match, it should return a printed message. However, it is not returning anything, even if they match.

```
#storing passwords in an external file
file = open("passwordlearn.csv", "a+")
password = input("Please enter a password: ")
file.write(password + "\n")
file.close()

#opening a connection to password.csv
temp = open("passwordlearn.csv", "r")
password = temp.read()
temp.close()

#splitting the string up
eachPassword = password.split ("\n")

#creating a list
newlistthree=[]
for eachItem in eachPassword:
    record = eachItem.split(",")
    newlistthree.append(record)
print(newlistthree)

#creating a list with the blank deleted
newlistfour=[]
for eachItem in eachPassword:
    record = eachItem.split(",")
    newlistfour.append(record)
del newlistfour[-1]
print(newlistfour)
firstpassword = newlistfour.pop()
print(firstpassword)

#authentication
passwordcheck = input("Please type your password again: ")
if passwordcheck == firstpassword:
    print("Passwords Match. Please login.")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code and found that `firstpassword` is a list with one element and `passwordcheck` is just a string.

Thus, in `if passwordcheck == firstpassword:` it ends up comparing `'example_password'` and `['example_password']`, so it will always be false.

You might want to rethink how you are cleaning and storing your passwords to make `newlistfour` not a list of one element lists, but for your code, if you change it to `if passwordcheck == firstpassword[0]:` then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is this line `record = eachItem.split(",")`, when you do a split in a string the returned object is a list and not a string. Then at the end what you are trying to compare is a string with a list which is not the same.

Although it is not clear for me why you are trying to split the password you could make your code work by skipping this split or adding to 'newlistthree' just the password string like this:

```
newlistthree.append(record[0])
```